# When the word TRIGONOMETRY is permuted, what it that probability that it begins with T or ends with O?

Tags: probability

account for repeated digits.

I added up cases when it (begins with t) + (ends with O) - (begins with t and ends with o)

anyone know the answer?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: did u get a final answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did what you just said.

Got $9,979,200 + 9,979,200 - 1,814,400 = 18,144,000$

[This](http://webviewworks.com/cgi-bin/math/perm_calculator_word.cgi) tool came handy.

Answer (score 0):

Though PIE is the way to go, don't over complicate it.

(Assuming all possible permutations are equally probable:)   What is the probability for selecting $1$ from $2$ "$T$" or $1$ from $2$ "$O$", in first and last position respectively, when selecting $2$ from $12$ letters in order and without replacement?

> $$\frac 2{12}+\frac{2}{12}- \frac 2{12}\cdotp\frac{2}{11}~=~\frac {10}{33}$$